# fancybox - show ajax content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have an anchor tag with a click event on it

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:     'ajax/test.php',
    data:    {id: 123, count: 456},
    success: function(data) {
               //lightbox data
             }
  });
});
```

The response will look something like

```
{
  title: 'My Title',
  body:  'My Body'
}
```

I want to show this in a fancybox.

Where I am stuck is creating and showing a fancybox around this content on the fly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
success: function(data) {
  $.fancybox({
    'content' : '<h1>' + data.title + '</h1>' + data.body
  });
}
```

Comment: hey jarrett, ive tried using these code but it kinda disable the fancybox But it proceed to load to the page specificied in HREF from the anchor. any reason why?

Comment: @lilsizzo Have you tried opening a question for this? If you have not, when you do I'd recommend posting the code you are using.

Comment: @JarrettWidman Unfortunately, it did not worked for me. Could you please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351626/jquery-fancybox-with-ajax/31352383)  question? Thanks in advance.